# Is it possible to create a biological radio?

Tags: cell-biology, electrophysiology

If someone had taken the genome for a basic single or multi-celled organism, and had the understanding of genetic code to write his own program, is it possible on a fundamental level to create the organelles necessary to emit an electromagnetic signal at a frequency that isn't widely used by modern day electronics (noise concerns)?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This type of question are off-topic here. You might want to give it a try on [WorldBuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Note: Bioluminescence is a type of electromagnetic signal. Gymnotoid fish use electric signals to communicate (mainyl for courtship if I am not mistaken). Electric discharges (e.g. eels) might count too. Also, any neuron that fires causes an electromagnetic signal. You don't need to do any genetic engineering to get an animal that produce an electromagnetic signal! You should clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: Albeit interesting question, what @Remi.b refers to are the additional senses of *[magnetoception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetoreception)* and *[electroception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroreception)*. However, i think your are talking about something else. Please clarify.